# Issue with editing list<double[]> in c#

Tags: c#, list

I am passing a list of type double[] to a function in a class, editing the values within a function using a tempList, then returning the edited values.
But the originalList being passed is being edited as well which I do not want them edited to match the tempList.

Here is the code.

```
List<double[]> newList = new List<double[]();
newList = myClass.myFunction(value, originalList);

// myClass
...

// myFunction
public List<double[]> myFunction(int value, List<double[]> myList)
{
    List<double[]> tempList = new List<double[]>();
    for (int i = 0; i < myList).Count; i++)
    {
       tempList.Add(myList[i]);
    }


    // Do stuff to edit tempList

    return tempList;
}
```

Comment: What is actually your question, what do you want to do? You can edit the original list<T>, you dont need to create a new one.

Answer (score 4):

Bear in mind that arrays are *reference* types. When you add an array to `tempList`, only a reference to the array is being added, so that `myList` and `tempList` both refer to the same `double[]` objects.

Instead, you need to make a clone of the arrays:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myList.Count; i++)
{
   tempList.Add((double[])myList[i].Clone());
}
```

Comment: Yes, but the code looks dodgy in the first place. Cloning an array is rarely the right thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

An array, `here double[]`, is a reference type, so the line

```
tempList.Add(myList[i]);
```

is adding a reference to the original array.  Then when you edit tempList you're editing the original array.  Make a copy like this:

```
tempList.Add(myList[i].ToArray());
```

Answer (score 1):

You are adding the reference to the array to the new list, but not making a copy of the contents of each array.  Your copy should look something like this:

```
foreach (double[] item in myList)
{
    double[] copy = new double[item.Length];
    Array.Copy(item, copy);
    templist.Add(copy);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is `double[]` is a reference type, not a value type, so when you are adding it to your `tempList`, you are adding a reference to the original object, not a new object.  You actually need to create a new `double[]` before adding it to `tempList` so you are not working on the original object.

Assuming you can use LINQ, you do not need to loop.  You can do something like:

```
var tempList = myList.Select(x => x.ToArray()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because Collections/reference types are passed by reference. (Actually the holding variable is passed by value, but the all variables point to same reference).

For detail explanation, read [this SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10687880/649524)

If you want that modifications in my Function does not reflect in original collection, you have to copy/clone it and then pass to `myFunction`.

Example

```
newList = myClass.myFunction(value, (List<double>)originalList.Clone());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tempList.Add(myList[i]);
```

means that you add the reference to the double[] object on index i to temp list.
therefore, if you edit the value of that object, you will get the chances on both of the lists.

if you want to have a different cloned lists that won't affect each other you will have to do that:

```
List<double[]> tempList = new List<double[]>();
for (int i = 0; i < myList).Count; i++)
{
   double[] originalListItem = myList[i];

   // the most important step here!!! - clone the originalListItem to clonedListItem

   tempList.Add(clonedListItem);
}


// Do stuff to edit tempList

return tempList;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are copying the double[] reference to the new list, this is a shallow copy.
You need a deep copy and create new double arrays to edit the temp arrays without changing the original arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You are inserting references to the array in the tempList, not a copy of the array. So if you change a value in the tempList, you are changing the original array.

This code will work better:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < myList.Count; i++)
    {
       var copy = new Double[myList[i].Length];
       Array.Copy(myList[i], copy, myList[i].Length);
       tempList.Add(copy);
    }
```